# Ability to set multiselect but ONLY one OptGroup in bootstrap is it possible?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

**This is sample code.
Using jQuery It works Fine but when i put this in code using bootstrap it does not works
bootstrap override this jQuery code**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frJEq/81/)

```html
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
    <optgroup label="MyGroup">
        <option>Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="MyGroup2">
        <option>Option5</option>
        <option>Option6</option>
        <option>Option7</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="MyGroup3">
        <option>Option8</option>
        <option>Option9</option>
        <option>Option10</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mySelect").change(function() {
    var selected = $(':selected', this);
    var selopt = selected.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    if (selopt == "MyGroup") {
      $('optgroup[label=MyGroup2]').prop('disabled', true);
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    } else {
      $('optgroup[label=MyGroup2]').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
    if (selopt == "MyGroup2") {
      $('optgroup[label=MyGroup]').prop('disabled', true);
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    } else {
      $('optgroup[label=MyGroup]').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <optgroup label="MyGroup">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="MyGroup2">
    <option>Option5</option>
    <option>Option6</option>
    <option>Option7</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[This is working js fiddle with all links](http://jsfiddle.net/frJEq/88/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the code on line number 7 and 16 as per JSFiddle

```
$('optgroup[label=MyGroup2]').prop('disabled', true);
```

and

```
$('optgroup[label=MyGroup]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azcjmLk6/)

Comment: But Why? I want that function.Have you read the question carefully.

Comment: I want that user can select multiple option but from only one optgroup

Comment: I'm using modified bootstrap select js  which conflicts with this one

Comment: I interpreted it wrongly. Can you add the JSFiddle for the same with you bootstrap issue